# Функции с переменным числом параметров в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно передать функции заранее неизвестное число аргументов. Как объявлять такие функции я знаю, хотелось бы узнать, каков синтаксис вызова такой функции, при условии, что аргументы лежат в списке, а число аргументов хранится в отдельной переменной.

Comment: как-то не очевидно, в чем собственно вопрос. Вот про это `lst = [аргументы]; n=число аргументов; myfunc(*lst[:n])` ?

Comment: Напишите пример использования такой функции, что вообще хочется, а то не очень понятно.

Answer (score 3):

Функция объявляется так

```
def foo(*args):
    for a in args:
        print(a)
```

Звездочка тут собирает переданные аргументы в список

Вызов обычный

```
foo(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

Вызов если аргументы уже в листе:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
foo(*lst)
```

Звездочка тут раскладывает список в аргументы.

Число аргументов тут не используется потому как списки в Питоне имеют размер в себе. Для Си такие параметры передаются указателем и размер списка там необходим.